# Decode for multiple rows and columns in Oracle SQL

Tags: oracle, for-loop, if-statement, plsql, decode

I have a table(details)-

| Name(primary key) | color | shading | available |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | Y | N | N |
| B | N | Y | Y |
| C | N | N | N |

Now, I want a query that checks rows as well as columns one by one for each record.
For eg,

```
if color = "Y" then output = "ABC"
if color = "N" and shading = "Y" then output = "XYZ"
if color = "N" and shading = "N" and available = "Y" then output = "Hurray!"
```

Priority for column goes like - color>shading>available
So, if color = "Y" we don't need to look at other 3 columns and give the output as "ABC"
Similarly, it should check output values for all the rows and eventually only give **only one output** according to priority.
Priority goes as follows - ABC>XYZ>Hurray! i.e. if any of the 3 rows gives output as "ABC" final output should be "ABC". But if 2 rows give output "Hurray!" and one row gives output "XYZ" final output should be "XYZ".

I tried using decode.

```
SELECT DECODE (color,'Y','ABC') AS RESULT_color,
DECODE (shading,'Y','XYZ') AS RESULT_shade,
DECODE (available,'Y','Hurray!') AS RESULT_available from details;
```

But this is wrong because it only considers one column and one row at a time when I want to check all the columns and all the rows together.

Comment: Sounds like you need a CASE statement. Define your top priority condition as the first WHEN clause, then your next priority as the next WHEN clause, etc..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQL query while selecting threats every row separately (most of the time), so `CASE`, `DECODE` and other functions and expression will work with one row at a time.

You, as I understand, want to analyze table as a whole. It seems like not really SQL's task, but you could "hack" your way out.

You can analyze rows one at a time, and then calculate output for whole table.

Here query:

1. based on values in columns assigns priority to rows,
2. gets maximum priority of rows,
3. decodes this maximum value into desired strings.

```sql
select
    DECODE (max(priority),
        3, 'ABC',
        2, 'XYZ',
        1, 'Hurray!',
        'BAD!')
from (
    select
        CASE
            WHEN (color = 'Y') THEN 3
            WHEN (
                color = 'N'
                AND shading = 'Y'
            ) THEN 2
            WHEN (
                color = 'N'
                AND shading = 'N'
                AND available = 'Y'
            ) THEN 1
            ELSE 0
        END priority
    from details
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `CASE` over `DECODE`. `DECODE` is great when you have a single simple equality or inequality choice and you want to have succinct, clean looking code. But anything more complex than that you can handle much better with `CASE`. Like most `CASE` implementations in languages, in SQL it will evaluate in order of the test conditions, so you can control priority simply by the order of your `WHEN` clauses:

```
SELECT x.*,
       CASE WHEN (color = 'Y') THEN 'ABC'
            WHEN (color = 'N' AND shading = 'Y') THEN 'XYZ'
            WHEN (color = 'N' AND shading = 'N' AND available = 'Y') THEN 'Hurray!'
       END output
  FROM table x
```

Comment: Thanks! But I need to add this inside a loop to check the output for all rows. The Case WHEN that you have shared only takes care of the columns. And even if I put this in a loop, suppose the output of first row comes as 'XYZ' and second comes as 'ABC' it should print 'ABC'. So, do I need to store the output of each row (after applying a loop) into some array or table and then after getting all the outputs, I check that table/array again to get one final output.

Comment: Your table has multiple rows. When you SELECT from it just once, you get multiple rows, and the CASE logic applies to each one. You'll get an "output" value for every row with a single SELECT execution. If that's not what you're after, please also post your looping code so we can see what you're trying to do.

Answer (score -1):

You can use CASE statement for this use case.
For your question try using this snippet.

```
SELECT 
    CASE
        WHEN 'ABC' IN (
            SELECT
                CASE
                    WHEN color = 'Y' THEN 'ABC'
                    WHEN color = 'N' AND shading = 'Y' THEN 'XYZ'
                    WHEN color = 'N' AND shading = 'N' AND available = 'Y' THEN 'Hurray!'
                END
            FROM details) THEN 'ABC'
        WHEN 'XYZ' IN (
            SELECT
                CASE
                    WHEN color = 'Y' THEN 'ABC'
                    WHEN color = 'N' AND shading = 'Y' THEN 'XYZ'
                    WHEN color = 'N' AND shading = 'N' AND available = 'Y' THEN 'Hurray!'
                END
            FROM details) THEN 'XYZ'
        ELSE 'Hurray!'
    END
FROM details;
```

Comment: This isn't valid Oracle SQL. You can't use double quotes around string values like that, and you don't alias the name after the CASE keyword, but after END.

Comment: Thanks! But I need to add this inside a loop to check the output for all rows. The Case WHEN that you have shared only takes care of the columns. And even if I put this in a loop, suppose the output of first row comes as 'XYZ' and second comes as 'ABC' it should print 'ABC'. So, do I need to store the output of each row (after applying a loop) into some array or table and then after getting all the outputs, I check that table/array again to get one final output.